# HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: ConsumerAgentAccount, getter method of property: id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish, illegalargumentexception

Help! After a lot of research on this site and on the internet in general, I have been unable to find a solution. I have a Hibernate 4.3.6/Glassfish 4.0 project that deploys fine, but throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when I try to persist a new object into the database. I have used this setup on other servers in the past with no problems so again, I am at a loss.

There are three entities at the center of this problem:

```
    @Entity
    @Cacheable(false)
    public class ConsumerAgentAccount implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6862398628955419461L;

        private long id = 0L;
        private Account account = null;
        private String firstName = null;
        private String lastName = null;
        private boolean active = true;
        private long bornOn = 0L;

        private ConsumerAccount consumerAccount;

        public ConsumerAgentAccount() { super(); }

        @PrePersist
        private void onPersist()
        {
            bornOn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        public long getId()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Embedded
        public Account getAccount()
        {
            return account;
        }
        public void setAccount(Account account)
        {
            this.account = account;
        }

        @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName)
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Column(nullable=false)
        public boolean isActive()
        {
            return active;
        }
        public void setActive(boolean active)
        {
            this.active = active;
        }

        @Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
        public long getBornOn()
        {
            return this.bornOn;
        }
        public void setBornOn(long bornOn)
        {
            this.bornOn = bornOn;
        }

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
        public ConsumerAccount getConsumerAccount()
        {
            return consumerAccount;
        }
        public void setConsumerAccount(ConsumerAccount consumerAccount)
        {
            this.consumerAccount = consumerAccount;
        }
    }

@Embeddable
public class Account
{
    private String email = null;
    private String password = null;

    public Account() { super(); }

    public Account(String email, String password)
    {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false, length=100)
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false, length=20)
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class ConsumerAccount implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3886143395284500664L;

    private long id = 0L;
    private Account account = null;
    private String name = null;
    private boolean active = true;
    private long bornOn = 0L;

    private List<ConsumerAgentAccount> consumerAgentAccounts = null;
    private List<WebFormProfile> webFormProfiles = null;

    public ConsumerAccount() { super(); }

    @PrePersist
    private void onPersist()
    {
        bornOn = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Embedded
    public Account getAccount()
    {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account)
    {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false, length=75)
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public boolean isActive()
    {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active)
    {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    public long getBornOn()
    {
        return this.bornOn;
    }
    public void setBornOn(long bornOn)
    {
        this.bornOn = bornOn;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="consumerAccount")
    public List<ConsumerAgentAccount> getConsumerAgentAccounts()
    {
        System.out.println("getconsumeragentaccounts");
        return consumerAgentAccounts;
    }
    public void setConsumerAgentAccounts(List<ConsumerAgentAccount> consumerAgentAccounts)
    {
        this.consumerAgentAccounts = consumerAgentAccounts;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="consumerAccount")
    public List<WebFormProfile> getWebFormProfiles()
    {
        return webFormProfiles;
    }
    public void setWebFormProfiles(List<WebFormProfile> webFormProfiles)
    {
        this.webFormProfiles = webFormProfiles;
    }
}
```

Here's my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="inserteck_punit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/inserteck</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/namedqueries.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ConsumerAccount</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ConsumerAgentAccount</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ProfileField</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ProviderAccount</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ProviderProfile</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ProviderProfileMessage</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.SuggestedWebFormFieldMapping</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.WebFormField</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.WebFormFieldMapping</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.WebFormProfile</class>

        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.Account</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.Address</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.EducationInfo</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.FinancialInfo</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.PersonalInfo</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.SensitiveInfo</class>
        <class>com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.embeds.WorkInfo</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name" value="EJB.EMF.ITK"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the block of code in one of my EJB's that causes the error:

```
        ConsumerAccount consumerAccount = new ConsumerAccount();
        consumerAccount.setName("blah Enterprises, LLC.");
        consumerAccount.setActive(true);
        consumerAccount.setAccount(new Account("blah@blah.com", "blahblah"));
        consumerAccount.setConsumerAgentAccounts(new ArrayList<ConsumerAgentAccount>(0));
        consumerAccount.setWebFormProfiles(new ArrayList<WebFormProfile>(0));

        ConsumerAgentAccount consumerAgentAccount = new ConsumerAgentAccount();
        consumerAgentAccount.setFirstName("Splatt");
        consumerAgentAccount.setLastName("Testerman");
        consumerAgentAccount.setActive(true);
        consumerAgentAccount.setAccount(new Account("s@test.com", "A1"));
        consumerAgentAccount.setConsumerAccount(consumerAccount);

        consumerAccount.getConsumerAgentAccounts().add(consumerAgentAccount);

        entityManager.persist(consumerAccount);
        entityManager.persist(consumerAgentAccount);
```

And this is the stack trace from the Glassfish log file:

```
[2015-03-10T05:09:08.479+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor] [tid: _ThreadID=58 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1425964148479] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ConsumerAgentAccount, getter method of property: id]]

[2015-03-10T05:09:08.491+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [ejb.system_exception] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=58 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1425964148491] [levelValue: 900] [[
  EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CoreController, method: public javax.json.JsonObject com.blushiftss.inserteck.CoreController.initDatabase(javax.json.JsonObject)]]

[2015-03-10T05:09:08.491+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=58 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1425964148491] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:662)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy281.initDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at com.blushiftss.inserteck.__EJB31_Generated__CoreController__Intf____Bean__.initDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at com.blushiftss.inserteck.ws.AdminResource.initDatabase(AdminResource.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy284.initDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at com.blushiftss.inserteck.ws.__EJB31_Generated__AdminResource__Intf____Bean__.initDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ConsumerAgentAccount.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at com.blushiftss.inserteck.CoreController.initDatabase(CoreController.java:1003)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.blushiftss.inserteck.entities.ConsumerAgentAccount.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    ... 136 more
]]
```

I am at a loss. If I persist the two new entities in the opposite order, it throws the exception on the other one. I think the issue is related to the fact that I have embedded classes in my entities but I have used this structure before with no problems. Grrrr.

**UPDATE**

I have deployed this application to another Glassfish server of the exact same build 4.0 u 89 and it is working fine. The difference is that the server I need this to run on is tied to MySQL and the one where it works now is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. I was using Hibernate 4.3.6, but when I downgraded to 4.3.5, it fixed my problem. I don't know if there's a bug in 4.3.6+ (as I also tried 4.3.8 and it failed) but when you use this version, it throws the above error when you try to persist an entity containing an embedded field/object.

Comment: I've just opened a [ticket about this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10093), since I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devtool with spring boot it is going to throw

> HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class:

Another exception was

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

I went nuts looking for the solution. And finally, I got the solution from
[this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/24053413916/)
I had tried many things, entity mapping, configuration files not once but many times.

Please remove dev tool dependency from your pom.xml. clean it and build it again. Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: This answer may not address the original question but it saved me. I have spent half a day debugging this weird issue.